# Why query is getting unrecognized RTE kind: 2 (PG16 - AGE16)

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

We are having an issue while execution of the queries that contains join conversed subquery from apache age's parser to PostgreSQL's parser

**OPTIONAL MATCH with MATCH cause that error**

The following query

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_match', $$
    MATCH (u:opt_match_v)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[m]-(l)
    RETURN u.name as u, type(m), l.name as l
    ORDER BY u, m, l
$$) AS (u agtype, m agtype, l agtype);
```

Throws

```bash
ERROR:  unrecognized RTE kind: 2
```

Modifications done o [`transform_cypher_optional_match_clause`](https://github.com/muhammadshoaib/age/blob/cf5046e1b1dc6214c09e26471d53de9dd83b5cd0/src/backend/parser/cypher_clause.c#L2469C23-L2546) function
After setting up the rtindex as we are expecting that to be modified based on `addRangeTableEntryForJoin` call I am getting into the following error, it is being thrown from the executor

```
    jnsitem = addRangeTableEntryForJoin(pstate,
                                        res_colnames,
                                        NULL,
                                        j->jointype,
                                        0,
                                        res_colvars,
                                        NIL,
                                        NIL,
                                        j->alias,
                                        NULL,
                                        false);
    j->rtindex = jnsitem->p_rtindex;
```

###### I have added the following after that above line

```
    RangeTblRef* rtr = (RangeTblRef*)j->rarg;
    rtr->type = j->rarg->type;
    rtr->rtindex = j->rtindex;
```

###### What was the output before adding my modifications:

```bash
ERROR:  graph_oid and label_id must not be null
```

###### What am trying to solve?

Resolving the new added rteperminfos attribute on the PNSI struct of PostgreSQL to make it compatible with Apache AGE.

###### What is the struggling we ran into?

- Having a correct value for rtindex for the constructed subquery from cypher function call
- Having a correct value for ParseState/ParseNamespaceItem (p_rteperminfos) (same **for** above)
- Also we got ran into some cases lead to `invalid perminfoindex 1 in RTE`

###### Versions

`PostgreSQL version: 16betav1`
`AGE version: 16`

##### References:

- https://dev.to/rrrokhtar/what-is-going-in-age-pg16-6hb
- https://age.apache.org/
- https://github.com/muhammadshoaib/age/tree/dev/PG16
- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/REL_16_STABLE